# Is it possible to add an HTML Snippet to Numbers on OS X?

Tags: numbers

Is it possible to add an HTML Snippet to Numbers on OS X?

I would like to add some html code and have Numbers treat it as such, for example to use iframes embed websites into my document.

Would this be possible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently.

**Numbers** does not have a **Safari** or **WebKit** rendering engine to translate HTML, CSS and JavaScript so as to render content marked up for the Web.  This functionality is currently not supported in **Microsoft Excel** or even **Google Sheets** either.

[See this similar answer related to Google Sheets on WebApps Stack Exchange.](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/50332/90425)  The [user](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/48419/tom-horwood) there explains:

> Google docs won't actually render HTML, or execute any code pasted
>   into it.